# Multiple threads JIRA API call problems

Tags: php, multithreading, curl, jira, jira-rest-api

I now come with a problem of overloading.

Via PHP i'm starting multiple threads to retrive issue from a specific (the same) jql. I'm doing this to retrive multiple issues( thousands of them) faster. 
Normal call in my environment would be for 10k issue => 200 got and processed by each threads so=> 50 threads. I surely can lower the stakes, let's say 1000 issues per thread. But i want it faster than normaly.

A curl call would get the 10k issues in aprox. 8 mins.

What i want is to know if it exists any limit on JIRA regarding max req per second/minute/user, because i surely notice some overloading on system. And this doesn't seem something very big.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that there is no limit regarding max requeste per second. Performance of the system will suffer only if RAM isn't enough.

[Jira Sizing Guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/ENTERPRISE/JIRA+Sizing+Guide) is a very good to start with.

Thing i had to look at was max concurrent logged in users (each request was a new login) and size of data which had to be retrieven. On 8gb i found to be ok (not overloading server) 4 concurrent threads (requests/logins) and 400 issues retrievent by each request.

Thanks :)